# Linux Mint 18 KDE and notification badges on taskbar icons

Tags: linux-mint, kde, notifications

I've installed Linux Mint 18 KDE and I'm trying to enable notification badges for program icons in the taskbar/panel (not system tray). Are they supported by Mint 18 KDE and how could I enable them? Thank you in advance.

EDIT - Here is a screenshot of Windows 10 taskbar with a badge (see the arrow), I'd like to obtain the same result on Linux Mint 18 KDE.

[image]

Comment: systray is the notification area

Comment: I know that, but I'd like to have badgers also on icons of the taskbar. Is there a way to enable them?